# Best way to view Tor logs and network stats using Tor via Homebrew?

Tags: mac, stats, nyx

I have installed Tor using Homebrew and configured torrc for client and bridge relay usage. However I would like to be able to see stats similar to what is available in Vidalia network monitor and log viewer. I understand ARM should give me what I'm after but I am not sure how to run it. Also under /usr/local/Cellar/tor/... I can tail -f a number a files such as state and bridge-stats but this does not seem give me the rich detail that was available with Vidalia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit (after realizing Homebrew is a osx only pakage manager):

on OS X:

**To install arm:**
Simply install arm using `brew install arm`.

**To just view the logs:**
`var/log` dir doesn't exist by defult. You need ot make it under `/usr/local/Cellar/tor/{Tor version}/` and perhaps turn notices or debug logs on in your torrc. And Tor will print logs on `/usr/local/Cellar/tor/{Tor version}/var/log/notices.log` or `/usr/local/Cellar/tor/{Tor version}/var/log/debug.log`.

or point torrc to elsewhere to print the logs.

---

on linux:

I don't think if that's a good idea (or recommended) to install Tor using non-official package managers.

**To install Tor:**
See installation guide for [Debian/Ubuntu](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en#ubuntu) or [Fedora/CentOS](https://www.torproject.org/docs/rpms.html.en) to learn how to add official Tor package repository to your linux machine to get the latest versions first hand.

**To install and run arm:**
Once you added Tor repositories and installed latest version of Tor, you can install arm using `sudo apt-get install tor-arm` (if on Debian/Ubuntu) or `sudo yum install tor-arm` (if Fedora/CentOS) and then run arm with the same UID running/controlling Tor.

For example, run `sudo -u debian-tor arm` if installed from official repo on a Debian/Ubuntu machine.

**To just see the logs:**
You can control where Tor does write it's logs in your torrc. It must be `/var/log/tor/log` if you didn't change anything.

Comment: duh, I just realized Homebrew is a Mac OS X only package manager.

Comment: Yes and documented on Tor docs @ https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-osx.html.en However you pointed me in the right direction and after installing 'brew install arm' arm is now working which was my best case scenario. So answer accepted.

Comment: Could this answer be edited to reflect that 'brew install arm' will do it, since it's been accepted but is for Linux, not OS X?